# How to insert an object thats not sns as one of the subplots?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm working with a Pandas Dataframe in python and want to look at the properties of each column.

For each variable, I want to print the distplot, the boxplot, and lastly the description of that variable as a Series.

I can perfectly separate my plot in 3 subplots and show the first two plots. However, I don't know how to add the Describe table as the last "plot" of the output, because it is not a Seaborn object. As you can see, right now my third plot is in blank because that is supposed to be replaced with the table.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,5), ncols=3)
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
sns.distplot(df2['VarMCT3Camp'], ax = ax[0])
sns.boxplot(x=df2["VarMCT3Camp"], ax = ax[1])
```

[image: output]

This is the description table I would like to appear next to the other plots:

```
df2['VarMCT3Camp'].describe()

count    15605.000000
mean        11.016673
std         39.523005
min        -74.166667
25%        -12.500000
50%          4.166667
75%         25.000000
max        541.666667
Name: VarMCT3Camp, dtype: float64
```

I am working on Python3 with Anaconda3 on a Windows10

Comment: You add a text object to an axes with `ax.text()`. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Also, you can add a table with [`ax.table`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.table.html?highlight=table#matplotlib.axes.Axes.table)

Comment: Or you can plot a dataframe as a table from `pandas`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#plotting-tables

Comment: `from pandas.plotting import table` See [Plotting Tables](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#plotting-tables)

Comment: adapting from [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#plotting-tables), you can do:
`from pandas.plotting import table` and 
 `table(ax[2], np.round(df2['VarMCT3Camp'].describe(), 2))`